# Iterable toList() throws - ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (input): Must not be null)

Tags: list, flutter, dart, iterable

I am trying to make a list out of my iterable but it throws the following error

> Exception has occurred. ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (input):
> Must not be null)

on the toList() of

```
List<ContactModel> iterable = (await pluginContactService.ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false))
    .where((contact) => contact.phones.firstWhere((item) => item.label == 'mobile', orElse: () => null)?.value != null)
    .map((contact) => ContactModel(
        contact.displayName, contact.phones.firstWhere((item) => item.label == 'mobile').value)).toList(growable: false);
```

It keeps repeating this exception over and over again. If I turn exceptions off I get back a list with the expected results. What can I do about this exception?

Comment: you better use code instead of image when want to show code.

Comment: updated the question @JerryZhou

Comment: line number, character number? point out where exactly the output showing the problem is

Comment: The exception shows up on the .toList(growable: false); at the end

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ArgumentError(Invalid argument(s) input: must not be null)` means `.toList(growable: false);` calls on `null`.

So you should check if it's null before you call `.toList()` or use a default value like `?? []` to fix this error.

`?? []` can fix.

```dart
final tmp = (await pluginContactService
    .ContactsService
    .getContacts(withThumbnails: false)
)
    .where(
       (contact) => contact.phones.firstWhere(
        (item) => item.label == 'mobile', 
        orElse: () => null
       )?.value != null
    )
    .map((contact) => ContactModel(
        contact.displayName, 
        contact.phones.firstWhere(
           (item) => item.label == 'mobile'
        ).value)
     );
List<ContactModel> iterable = tmp == null? [] : tmp.toList(growable: false);
```

Comment: It does not fix the problem. Could you maybe explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: It still generates the exception.

Comment: @MikeOttink try the new one pls.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

turning off the "Break on All Exception" in your debug session settings fixes this.